# NSLog performance decrease in production

Tags: ios, nslog

I have an app that is ready to publish to an App Store. I have thousands of NSLog statements. I have 2 questions:

1 - if that logs output something, like values of array with hundreds elements, does that behaviour will work when user work with app? Will reduce it performance?

2 - Is there any option to refactor code, to simply comment all of `nslogs`, without explicitly do that manually?

Thanks.

Comment: ya surely it slows the performance , you can hide the NSLog and upload the new build to App Store,

Comment: Logging in a released version only fills up the devices of your user with rubbish.